# opacity scroll animation but reversed (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I have a scroll animation for the clouds but the animation should be reversed. How its working now is that it dissapears when its all the way scrolled up but it needs to be the other way around. [www.wytsepunter.com](http://www.wytsepunter.com) (also its very laggy on phone any tips for making that smoother?)

Here is the code:

```
let bg = document.getElementById('bg');
    let moon = document.getElementById('moon');
    let rock = document.getElementById('rock');
    let clouds = document.getElementById('clouds');
    let text = document.getElementById('text');

    window.addEventListener('scroll', function (){
        var value = window.scrollY;

        bg.style.top = value + 0.5 + 'px';
        moon.style.left = value * 0.5 + 'px';
        clouds.style.top = value * 0.5 + 'px';
        clouds.style.opacity = value * 0.5 + '%';
        text.style.top = value * 1 + 'px';
```

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you mean by the clouds "disappear"?  Is the opacity, position, or both not what you expect?  Why is there no initial opacity set on the clouds image?

Comment: How can the single property opacity be unclear? its either transparent or its visible. The only problem is that its now invisible when im scrolling up and visible when scrolling down but I need it to be the other way around